# change the order of a file

Tags: c#, file, sorting, ftp

I have code to order a file by date of creation, the first file is the newest
and the last is the oldest. How I reverse the ordering? This
means that the first file is the oldest and the last is the newest?

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://192.168.47.1/DocXML");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("User", "Pass");

FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();


List<string[]> files = new List<string[]> { };

string lookupString = @"^(?<dir>[\-ld])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+(?<filecode>\d+)\s+(?<owner>\w+)\s+(?<group>\w+)\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<hour>\d{1,2}):(?<minute>\d{2}))|((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<year>\d{4})))\s+(?<name>.+)$";
using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
{
    while (streamReader.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        files.Add(Regex.Split(streamReader.ReadLine(), lookupString));
    }
}
```

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b0axc2h2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.Reverse() on a list reverses the items within the list. Try:

```
files.Reverse();
```

Note: List.Reverse() is an in-place reverse; it doesn't return a new list.

Comment: and if I want to print to display the first file in the folder?  `textBox12.Text ==`????

Comment: sorry, I didn't get you.

Comment: I have a folder with the files, and I want to print in a textBox the list of the files

Comment: For example, In the first position from the folder I have a file with the name ""Jon.txt.", and in the second position from the folder The file´s name is "Jose.txt". And I want to print this name of the file in a textbox

Comment: Try: string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(path); and then loop through this array and print it in a textbox.

Comment: like this `string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles(files);`
           ` textBox12.Text = dirs[0];`

Comment: if u just want to display first file then it is correct bt if u want to display all files in textbox try this: textBox12.Text = String.Join("\n", dirs);